# Dreamweaver CS5 with ZF

Tags: zend-framework, dreamweaver

Anyone knows how to make code completion available in Dreamweaver CS5 with Zend Framework 1.10.*?

Also, using Discover doesn't work with my existing ZF application project opened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please contact the support, that's what you pay for ;) AFAIK Dreamweaver is not a programming IDE. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not used it with Zend, but Dreamweaver has a feature called Site Specific Code Hints that can be accessed from the following location in the menu system:
Site -> Site Specific Code Hints...

(make sure you have the site you're wanting to enable Zend framework code hints to selected in the Files panel)

Basically, within the Site Specific Code Hints interface, you'd create a new set of code hints (built in options for Drupal, Joomla, and Wordpress), and browse to the folder(s) that contain the files for the Zend framework, make sure to check the recursive box as appropriate. Once you apply the changes, Dreamweaver may churn for a while to generate the hints that it'll use within your site.

Here's the help documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WS367db1b80c96ca971172e08123ee174949-7fff.html